# Compressing Binary Numbers

Tags: python, binary, compression, bit

I have a list of 40-bit unique binary numbers that I want to compress into a form which would be less than 40-bits. Since every number is unique, I can't use techniques like the Huffman Coding. Any ideas about which algorithm I can use that would result effectively?

Comment: Could you say some more about what kind of list of integers it is? For example, do you expect the integers to form some contiguous ranges? Or be more likely to be multiples to some number? Anything like that?

Comment: I have 50 strings of binary numbers and they are growing incrementally since they represent the part after decimal point value of an Cumulative Distribution Table values. So, these binary numbers represent values between 0 and 1.

Comment: OK that's something. It does make the set of possible values smaller for each successive value, and that can be used (eg using a mixed-radix representation), but I expect that not many bits would be saved (unless the sequence gets close to 1.0 very quickly). Is there some other useful property? Maybe we can get a good "fit" for the CDF (in terms of some function that can be represented in a few bits, maybe a quadratic curve that has 0 and 1 as endpoints so with just one point in the middle we can tie it down), and then encode the deviations from that prediction?

Comment: I can't think of any other property right now